# How to debug VS add-in?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I am trying to modify a VS add-in, this addin has multiple projects. The addin project itself, some class librarys that it uses an an user interface project.

When I try to debug I get the error "A project with the output type of class library cannot be started directly." Since all projects essentially have the same output type, I am not sure what to do. I tried making sure the startup project is the actual vs addin project, and I still get the same errors. I have never worked with an add-in before so I figure I am probably missing an important step here. I am using vs 2010, and the addin targets that aswell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+debug+VS+add-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to specify Start external program property of Debug section of the project properties? Try to set a full path to Visual Studio exe (something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe")